# Failed to back to Menu from Game Over . Score unable to display on game over screen

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm very new to corona. I learned all from the web and this is what i produced. The game seems fine but when game over screen is displayed, the button i put to back to menu scene doesn't work and the score that player get failed to be displayed to..

Here is my code...someone kindly please help me out.. what code should i change or add to it??
Thank you. Any help is much appreciated.

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

local physics = require("physics")
local widget = require "widget"
physics.start()
rand = math.random( 20 )

local slap_sound = audio.loadSound("Sound/slap2.mp3")
local ow = audio.loadSound("Sound/ow.mp3")
local buttonSound = audio.loadSound("Sound/sound2.mp3")
local background
local back
local count={total1=0,total=0,touch=0,life=3}
local total
local time_remain = 5
local mossie
local bee
local shade
local gameOverScreen
local winScreen
local countdown
local life
local pauseBtn
local resumeBtn
local gametmr
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE
-- unless "composer.removeScene()" is called.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


local gameOver = function()

    composer.removeScene("easy")
    physics.pause()

    --audio.play(gameOverSound)
    background = display.newImageRect( "Images/bg.jpg", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    background.anchorX = 0
   background.anchorY = 0
   background.x, background.y = 0, 0
    gameOverScreen = display.newImage("Images/gameover.png",400,300)
    gameOverScreen.x = 160
    gameOverScreen.y = 240
    gameOverScreen.alpha = 0
    transition.to(gameOverScreen,{time=500,alpha=1})

    --total.isVisible = true
    total.text="Score : "..count.touch
    total.x = 160
    total.y = 400
    --total:setTextColor(000000)

    botwall.isVisible = false
    mossie.isVisible = false
    bee.isVisible = false
    life.isVisible = false
    countdown.isVisible = false
    pauseBtn.isVisible = false
    resumeBtn.isVisible = false

    local myButton = widget.newButton
    {
    left = 100,
    top = 100,
    id = "myButton",
    label = "Menu",
    onEvent = handleButtonEvent
    }

    myButton.isVisible = true

 end

local function handleButtonEvent( event )
    if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
        composer.gotoScene ("menu")
    end
end

local function countDown(e)
    time_remain = time_remain-1
    countdown.text = time_remain

    if time_remain == 0 then
      gameOver()
     end
end

local pauseGame = function(e)
    if(e.phase=="ended") then
        audio.play(buttonSound)
        physics.pause()
        timer.pause(gametmr)
        pauseBtn.isVisible = false
        resumeBtn.isVisible = true
        return true
    end
end

local resumeGame = function(e)
    if(e.phase=="ended") then
        audio.play(buttonSound)
        physics.start()
        timer.resume(gametmr)
        pauseBtn.isVisible = true
        resumeBtn.isVisible = false
        return true
    end
end

local collisionListener=function(self,event)
    if(event.phase=="began")then
        if(event.other.type=="mossie")then
            audio.play(ow)
            count.life=count.life-1
                if(count.life==0) then
                    gameOver()
                end 
            event.other:removeSelf()
            event.other=nil
        else
            event.other:removeSelf()
            event.other=nil
        end
    end 
end

function onTouch(mossie)
    audio.play(slap_sound)
    count.touch=count.touch+1
    total.text="Score : "..count.touch
    mossie.target:removeSelf()
end

function killIt(e)
    if(e.phase == "ended") then
        gameOver()
    end
end

local bottomWall = function()
    botwall=display.newImage("Images/tangan.png")
    botwall.x = 160
    botwall.y = 500
    botwall:setFillColor(22,125,185,255)
    botwall.type="botwall"
    botwall.collision=collisionListener
    physics.addBody(botwall,"static",{ density=100.0, friction=0.0, bounce=0.0} )
    botwall:addEventListener("collision",botwall)
end

local function newMossie(event)    
    total.text="Score : "..count.touch
    life.text="Life : "..count.life
    mossie = display.newImage("Images/biasa.png") 
    mossie.x = 60 + math.random( 160 )
    mossie.y = -100
    mossie.type="mossie"
    mossie:setFillColor(255,0,0)
    physics.addBody( mossie, { density=0.3, friction=0.2, bounce=0.5} )
    mossie.name = "mossie"
    mossie:addEventListener("touch",onTouch)
end 

local function newBee(event)
    bee = display.newImage("Images/lebah.png")
    bee.x = 60 + math.random( 160 )
    bee.y = -100
    bee.type="other"
    physics.addBody( bee, { density=1.4, friction=0.3, bounce=0.2} )
    bee:addEventListener("touch",killIt)
end


-- local forward references should go here

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view

   background = display.newImageRect( "Images/bg.jpg", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
   background.anchorX = 0
   background.anchorY = 0
   background.x, background.y = 0, 0

   total=display.newText("Score : 0",display.contentWidth * 0.5, 20, "Arial", 26)
   total:setTextColor(000000)

   countdown=display.newText(time_remain ,display.contentWidth * 0.9, 20, "Arial", 26)
   countdown:setTextColor(000000)

   life = display.newText("Life : 3 " ,display.contentWidth * 0.5, 50, "Arial", 26)
   life:setTextColor(000000)

   pauseBtn = display.newImage("Images/pause.png")
   pauseBtn.x = display.contentWidth * 0.1
   pauseBtn.y = display.contentHeight - 450

   resumeBtn = display.newImage("Images/playb.png") 
   resumeBtn.x = display.contentWidth * 0.1
   resumeBtn.y = display.contentHeight - 450

   botwall=display.newImage("Images/tangan.png")
   botwall.x = 160
   botwall.y = 500
   botwall:setFillColor(22,125,185,255)
   botwall.type="botwall"
   botwall.collision=collisionListener
   physics.addBody(botwall,"static",{ density=100.0, friction=0.0, bounce=0.0} )


   sceneGroup:insert(background)
   sceneGroup:insert(total)
   sceneGroup:insert(countdown)
   sceneGroup:insert(life)
   sceneGroup:insert(pauseBtn)
   sceneGroup:insert(resumeBtn)
   sceneGroup:insert(botwall)


   resumeBtn.isVisible = false
   pauseBtn:addEventListener("touch", pauseGame)
   resumeBtn:addEventListener("touch", resumeGame)
   botwall:addEventListener("collision",botwall)

   dropMossie = timer.performWithDelay( 2000 , newMossie, -1 )
   dropBee = timer.performWithDelay( 1800 , newBee, -1)
   gametmr = timer.performWithDelay(1000, countDown, -1)

   -- Initialize the scene here.
   -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.
end

-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view
   local phase = event.phase



   if ( phase == "will" ) then

      -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).
   elseif ( phase == "did" ) then


      -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
      -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive.
      -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
   end
end

-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view
   local phase = event.phase



   if ( phase == "will" ) then




      -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen).
      -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene.
      -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
   elseif ( phase == "did" ) then


      -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen.
   end
end

-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view
   --physics.stop()
   --timer.cancel(gametmr)
    --pauseBtn:removeEventListener("touch", pauseGame)
   --resumeBtn:removeEventListener("touch", resumeGame)
   --botwall:removeEventListener("collision",botwall)
   --bee:removeEventListener("touch",killIt)
   --mossie:removeEventListener("touch",onTouch)
   -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
   -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
   -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: hi, can u pleas help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make another composer scene for gameOverScreen (just like you did with these code block you post). Then do a composer.gotoScene(gameOver) read more [here](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/). And for the score I suggest that you make something like [this](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/05/28/tutorial-goodbye-globals/).

Answer (score 0):

The funtion **handleButtonEvent** is declared after you are creating a button widget. You can get the desired result by moving the function about the widget code.

```
    local function handleButtonEvent( event )
        if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
            composer.gotoScene ("menu")
        end
    end

    local myButton = widget.newButton
    {
        left = 100,
        top = 100,
        id = "myButton",
        label = "Menu",
        onEvent = handleButtonEvent
    }
    myButton.isVisible = true
end
```